# My imported variable isn't changing when I update it in the module file

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

navbar.ts

```
export let Home: boolean = true;
export let About: boolean = false;
export let Projects: boolean = false;
export let Contact: boolean = false;

export let pageStatus = {Home, About, Projects, Contact}
```

Header.svelte

```
import {pageStatus} from "$lib/header/navbar";
console.log(pageStatus)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested, you should use the store to share variable and save it to context, so in your index, you can create

```
<script>
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';
    const pageStatus = writable({
        Home: true, 
        About: false, 
        Projects: false, 
        Contact: false,
    })

    setContext('pageStatus')
</script>
```

then in your other component you can get the context data using

```
<script>
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';
    const pageStatus = getContext('pageStatus');
</script>

{#if $pageStatus.Home}
    <RenderSomethin/>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

When importing variables from other files you need to use [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) to get reactivity. Reactivity provided by the Svelte compiler on normal variables is only available within a single component and via component props.